# How to specify different emails for different git repos on the same machine

Tags: git

Im my home directory I have .gitconfig with these lines:

```
[user]
    name = Ivan Bessarabov
    email = ivan@bessarabov.ru
```

So, every commit I make has this name and email information. But I have
several repo on the same computer that need to have different email address.

How can I specify different email address for some repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in your repository directory:

```
git config user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
```

Without `--global` option it'll configure email specific for this repository (it'll be stored in `.git/config` file inside this repository directory).